# html tabledata(<td></td>) text not splitting if it doesn't contain a space

Tags: php, html-table

I made a small comment/logbook script which puts a Username, Comment and Date in my database.

I use a POST method to send this to my PHP script. Then I display everything in a table. But the 'Comment' goes "through" the tabledata if it doesn't contain a space. This is because the script doesn't know where to split it so it just prints it out whole.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['HandleAction']))
    {   
        if($_POST['User'] != '' && $_POST['Text'] != '')
        {
            $User = $_POST['User'];
            $Text = $_POST['Text'];
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO Comments VALUES('$User', '$Text', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)");
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<script>alert('Vul alle velden in om.');</script>";
        }
    }

    echo "Comments" . "<br>" . "<hr>";
    echo "<table id='Comments'>";
    $results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Comments");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results))
    {
        echo "<tr>  <th width='720'>" . $row['Name'] . "</th>   <th>" . $row['Date'] . "</th>   </tr>";
        echo "<tr>  <td>" . $row['Text'] . "</td>   </tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";    
?>
```

So long story short: my string can't split if it doesn't contain a string and makes my  way too long.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So what's the question? You want it to split the string? or you want the string to be forced to the next line within the `<td></td>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply the word wrap style to the td that is too long. Although this may distort the display because a long word may be split over multiple lines. You could restrict the amount of characters the user can type in, like twitter does or validate the input to have a maximum amount of characters per word.

Hope that helps

[See more information here on word wrap](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp)